# What is the most efficient way to create new Spark Tables or Data Frames in Sparklyr?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, dplyr, sparklyr

Using the `sparklyr` package on a Hadoop cluster (not a VM), I'm working with several types of tables that need to be joined, filtered, etc... and I'm trying to determine what would be the most efficient way to use the `dplyr` commands along with the data management functions in `sparklyr` to run processing, store it in cache, and work with the intermediate data objects to produce downstream objects that remain in cache. This question is superficial as it's posed above, but I'm hoping to get a little more information than pure efficiency, so if you'd like to edit my question, I'm ok with that...

I have some tables in Hive, let's call them `Activity2016`,`Accounts2016`, and `Accounts2017`. The "Accounts" tables also include address history. I want to start with 2016 data merging the two tables on name and present address, filter on some activity and account detail, then merge two different ways with 2017 account information, specifically to tally the number of people who remained at their address vs. those who changed address. We've got millions of rows, so we're doing this activity with our spark cluster.

So, to begin, this is what I'm doing now:

```
sc <- spark_connect()    

Activity2016 %>% filter(COL1 < Cut1 & COL1 > Cut2) %>% 
select(NAME,ADDRESS1) %>% 
inner_join(Accounts2016,c("NAME"="NAME","ADDRESS1"="ADDRESS1")) %>%
distinct(NAME,ADDRESS1) %>% sdf_register("JOIN2016")

tbl_cache(sc,"JOIN2016")
JOINED_2016 <- tbl(sc, "JOIN2016")

Acct2017 = tbl(sc, "HiveDB.Accounts2017")

# Now, I can run:
JOINED_2016 %>% inner_join(Acct2017,c("NAME"="NAME","ADDRESS1"="ADDRESS2")) %>%
distinct(NAME,ADDRESS1.x) %>% sdf_register("JOIN2017")

# Rinse & Repeat
tbl_cache(sc,"JOIN2017")
JOINED_2017 <- tbl(sc,"JOIN2017")
```

Then I continue working with `JOINED_2016` and `JOINED_2017`, using `dplyr` verbs, etc...

There seems to be multiple inefficiencies here... like, 
1) Shouldn't I be able to send it straight to cache and call it as a variable?
2) Shouldn't I also be able to send it straight into a written Hive table?
3) How can I cast the final object to run basic `R` commands like `table(JOINED_2016$COL1)` or are those unavailable (I'm getting errors when trying `%>% select(COL1) %>% table`)?

I'll lose the data if there's a downstream error and I don't write it... but I feel like there's too many choices about how to write the data that I'm not clear on. When does it end up as a cached object, versus an `RDD`, versus a Hive internal/external table, versus a Spark DataFrame and what constraints does each have with R's ability to work with those data objects?

For example, what if I just run:

```
JOIN2016 <- Activity2016 %>% filter(COL1 < Cut1 & COL1 > Cut2) %>% 
select(NAME,ADDRESS1) %>% 
inner_join(Accounts2016,c("NAME"="NAME","ADDRESS1"="ADDRESS1")) %>%
distinct(NAME,ADDRESS1)
```

Would this be an R `data.frame`? (that would potentially crash the RAM of my gateway node... which is why I'm reluctant to try it. This is a cluster at the business)

So summarizing: 
Should I bother with the `tbl` and `tbl_cache` commands at all or do I need them?

Should I use `dbWriteTable` and can I do it directly after, before, or in lieu of `sdf_register`... or do I need to use the `tbl` command before I can write anything to Hive? `sdf_register` almost seems pointless.

Should I use `copy_to` or `db_copy_to` instead of `dbWriteTable`? I don't want to turn Hive into a dumping ground, so I want to be careful about how I write the intermediate data and then be consistent about how R will work with it after I store it.

Which of these `data.frame`-type do I have to run to work with the data like it's an in-memory R object, or am I restricted to `dplyr` commands?

Sorry there's so much in this question, but I don't feel like there's clarity around these issues in the R-bloggers articles, the `sparklyr` tutorials, nor the other questions on SOF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sdf_register` is not very useful when dealing with  long running queries. It is basically an unmaterialized view which means it runs the underlying query each time you call it. Adding the following will write the data to Hive as a table.

`spark_dataframe %>% invoke("write") %>% invoke("saveAsTable", as.character("your_desired_table_name"))`

This uses `saveAsTable` as table which will create a table in have and keep that table even after the Spark session ends. Using `createOrReplaceTempView` does not persist the data when the Spark session ends.

Comment: Does this mean that, with a disconnect followed by a reconnect, that a new call needs to be run, i.e. `desired_tbl <- tbl("your_desired_table_name")` ?

Comment: Yes. The table  rested from this process is just like all other permanent Hive tables.

Comment: Also, when I check the `class` of this object, I get `"tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"`. In order to call functions that are applicable to a `data.frame`, it looks like the only thing we can do is run `mydf <- collect(desired_tbl)`.